# Getting https://localhost/myapp/saml/sso redirection throws 404 error - Spring MVC/Okta

Tags: java, spring-security, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, okta

I am trying to create SP initiated SSO on Spring MVC application with Okta idp. I am getting 404 after the redirection from idp with failed authentication with the below error message when i am doing localhost testing.

[image]

[image]

I have setup idp settings as follow

- Single Sign On URL : https://localhost/myapp/saml/SSO
- Recipient URL : https://localhost/myapp/saml/SSO
- Destination URL :https://localhost/myapp/saml/SSO
- Audience Restriction : https://localhost/myapp/saml/metadata

I am getting the below error on the Tomcat Server

```
2020-09-15 07:25:33 DEBUG SAMLProcessingFilter:206 - Request is to process authentication
2020-09-15 07:25:33 DEBUG SAMLProcessingFilter:345 - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Error validating SAML message
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Error validating SAML message
        at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:100) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar:1.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:87) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar:1.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar:1.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71) [log4j-web-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [catalina.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [catalina.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [catalina.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [catalina.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690) [catalina.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [catalina.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [catalina.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.37]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) [?:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.37]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]
Caused by: org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: InResponseToField of the Response doesn't correspond to sent message a4b12ga543g7jh7h5b0hcaef35g04i4
        at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:139) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar:1.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:87) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar:1.0.3.RELEASE]
        ... 47 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just fixed this issue from a [docs.sprint.io](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/chapter-troubleshooting.html) docuemntation. This made me crazy and finally able to resolve.

It seems my application was not using the same HttpSession during sending of the request and reception of the response.

Typically, this problem arises when the authentication request is initialized from localhost address or http scheme, while response is received at a public host name or https scheme. E.g., when initializing authentication from URL https://host:port/app/saml/login, the response must be received at https://host;port/app/saml/SSO, not https://host:port/app/saml/SSO or https://localhost:port/app/saml/SSO.

The checking of the InResponseToField can be disabled by re-configuring the context provider as follows:

```
<bean id="contextProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl">
      <property name="storageFactory">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.storage.EmptyStorageFactory"/>
      </property>
    </bean>
```